# How to disable elements on refresh?

Tags: javascript, velo

How do I disable elements on refresh? When I refresh the page all of the elements reset to their original state. They do not stay hidden as the code is written, could someone help me iron this out and tone the code to a functional point? This is written in Velo(Corvid) on top of Wix, any help is GREATLY appreciated, I have to get this project out by tomorrow :(.

```
import wixLocation from 'wix-location';

var HasBeenClicked
//element html1 is connected to a box with a script for a hack for loading the pg in a new tab, also #AudienceMember1 is connected to the url output in that script 
//-- all the rest of the elements follow the functions below
export function AudienceMember1_click(event) {$w('#html1').postMessage('POSTMESSAGEARGUMENT'); 
  
  let hideOptions = {
    'delay': 500,
    'duration': 1000
    };
  $w("#AudienceMember1").hide("fade,hideOptions");

  //Timer Function in milliseconds
  setTimeout(function() {
    $w("#AudienceMember1").show("fade"); 
  }, 7200000);

export function AudienceMember2_click(event) {$w('#html2').postMessage('POSTMESSAGEARGUMENT');
  
let hideOptions = {
    'delay': 500,
    'duration': 1000
    };
  $w("#AudienceMember2").hide("fade,hideOptions");
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    $w("#AudienceMember2").show("fade"); 
  }, 7200000);

}

export function AudienceMember3_click(event) {$w('#html3').postMessage('POSTMESSAGEARGUMENT');
  
let hideOptions = {
    'delay': 500,
    'duration': 1000
    };
  $w("#AudienceMember3").hide("fade,hideOptions");
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    $w("#AudienceMember3").show("fade"); 
  }, 7200000);

}

export function AudienceMember4_click(event) {$w('#html4').postMessage('POSTMESSAGEARGUMENT');
  
let hideOptions = {
    'delay': 500,
    'duration': 1000
    };
  $w("#AudienceMember4").hide("fade,hideOptions");
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    $w("#AudienceMember4").show("fade"); 
  }, 7200000);

}

export function AudienceMember5_click(event) {$w('#html5').postMessage('POSTMESSAGEARGUMENT');
  
let hideOptions = {
    'delay': 500,
    'duration': 1000
    };
  $w("#AudienceMember5").hide("fade,hideOptions");
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    $w("#AudienceMember5").show("fade"); 
  }, 7200000);

}

export function AudienceMember6_click(event) {$w('#html6').postMessage('POSTMESSAGEARGUMENT');
  
let hideOptions = {
    'delay': 500,
    'duration': 1000
    };
  $w("#AudienceMember6").hide("fade,hideOptions");
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    $w("#AudienceMember6").show("fade"); 
  }, 7200000);

}

export function AudienceMember7_click(event) {$w('#html7').postMessage('POSTMESSAGEARGUMENT');
  
let hideOptions = {
    'delay': 500,
    'duration': 1000
    };
  $w("#AudienceMember7").hide("fade,hideOptions");
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    $w("#AudienceMember7").show("fade"); 
  }, 7200000);

}

export function AudienceMember8_click(event) {$w('#html8').postMessage('POSTMESSAGEARGUMENT');
  
let hideOptions = {
    'delay': 500,
    'duration': 1000
    };
  $w("#AudienceMember8").hide("fade,hideOptions");
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    $w("#AudienceMember8").show("fade"); 
  }, 7200000);

}

export function AudienceMember9_click(event) {$w('#html9').postMessage('POSTMESSAGEARGUMENT');
  
let hideOptions = {
    'delay': 500,
    'duration': 1000
    };
  $w("#AudienceMember9").hide("fade,hideOptions");
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    $w("#AudienceMember9").show("fade"); 
  }, 7200000);

}

export function AudienceMember10_click(event) {$w('#html10').postMessage('POSTMESSAGEARGUMENT');
  
let hideOptions = {
    'delay': 500,
    'duration': 1000
    };
  $w("#AudienceMember10").hide("fade,hideOptions");
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    $w("#AudienceMember10").show("fade"); 
  }, 7200000);
}
```

Comment: You could use [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) to cache the page state, but a better solution might be to use the [beforeunload event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event) whichs allows the user to cancel the refresh to avoid loss of data.

Comment: ```import { local } from "wix-storage"

$w.onReady(function () {
    let btn2hasBeenClicked = local.getItem("btn2Clicked")

    if (btn2hasBeenClicked) {
        $w("#button2").hide
    } else {
        $w("#button2").show()
        }
    });
    
    export function button2_click(event) {
        local.setItem("btn2Clicked", "clicked")
        $w("#button2").enable

        setTimeout(function() {
    $w("#button2").show("fade"); 
  }, 10000);
    }

Comment: I tried this on a test page, how would I implement onReady function, and storage module into my first posted code. 


Is the code snippet above properly structured?

Comment: Change local.getItem() to session.getItem() and local.setItem() to session.setItem().  You want to use session so that btn2hasBeenClicked is cleared when the user closes the browser. Using local would make the value permanent and that could cause problems during the next visit. I see that your code sets btn2hasBeenClicked and also uses onReady().  To me your code looks ok, but you will need to test to confirm.

Comment: Button 1 works because theres no code to it still.

Button 2 is not working it is disabled on page load at the moment, I'm not sure what I did wrong but, it's disabled how I want it, but now I can't click it to make it hide then disable afterwards until my setimeout is done..

Comment: Made more changes, now btn2 hides but does not go to webpage and does not .show after set time.